# Rotating background of body element

Tags: css, css-transforms

How do I rotate the background of the body element using CSS transforms?  Rotating the content of the body element works fine, as does rotating the background of non-body elements:

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Smile-sad.svg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  
  div {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
</style>

<body>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  <div>
    BBBBB
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9x8p2kzd/1/

Why are the frowns not rotated by the same amount as the As, just as the smiles are rotated by the same amount as the Bs?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you rotate the body you're also rotating all of the children of the body.  Then, when you rotate the *children*, you're rotating them in *addition* to the rotation they've already received by being the child of a rotated element.

So your body + the divs *within* the body are being rotated `-45deg`, then the divs are being rotated a further `-20deg`, for a total perceived rotation of `-65deg`.

What effect are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't've used a single example to demonstrate both the expected behaviour when rotating a div and the strange behaviour when rotating the body. The total perceived rotation of `-65deg` for the div is just what I expected. I am trying to achieve rotation of a single tiled image, and was hoping to avoid having extra elements on the page as I am under tight size constraints.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the individual images in the body background?

Comment: I was expecting the background images in https://jsfiddle.net/mu2guh0v/ to be rotated as a whole, like in https://jsfiddle.net/nmtg8mpv/ (which is what I want, just without the extra div).

Comment: It's pretty standard practice to have a div wrapper for your page.  Attaching styles to the body directly can have unpredictable results.  Even if you do rotate the body, you'll need another div under it to then rotate your content back to what you want it to be.

Comment: I have no other content, just the background image.

Comment: Alternatively, you could apply the background-image to a pseudo element that you rotate (independently of the body).  Check out https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: No other content?  So there's nothing else on the page except the `body` with the background image?  As in, your markup looks like `<body></body>`?

Comment: I'm writing a rotozoomer. Every byte of markup is a byte less for my image. If I could remove the body tags entirely I would. To be clear, I'm not really asking how to achieve the effect I want so much as trying to clear up my confusion about why the idea I first tried didn't work. I thought I'd asked a precise, unambiguous question but clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

add class to parent div and apply transform on it

```
<style>
 .rotatebody{
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Smile-sad.svg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font-size: 80px;
  }
 .rotateinner {
   background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg);
   transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }

</style>
<body>
   <div class="rotatebody">
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      <div class="rotateinner">
         BBBBB
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```